# calculate $\sum_{1\le i\le r}\frac{i+1} { r+1}{2r-i\choose r-i}{s+i-2\choose i}+\frac{1}{r+1}{2r\choose r}$?

Tags: combinatorics

prove the following equation :
$$\sum_{1\le i\le r}\frac{i+1} { r+1}{2r-i\choose r-i}{s+i-2\choose i}+\frac{1}{r+1}{2r\choose r}={s+2r-1\choose r} - {s+2r-1\choose r-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\frac{1}{r+1} \sum_{q=0}^r (q+1) {2r-q\choose r-q}
{s-2+q\choose q} = {s+2r-1\choose r} - {s+2r-1\choose r-1}.$$

Introduce the integral representation

$${2r-q\choose r-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{2r-q}}{w^{r-q+1}}
\; dw$$

Note that this is zero when $q\gt r$ so we may extend $q$ to infinity,
getting for the sum

$$\frac{1}{r+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{2r}}{w^{r+1}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} (q+1)
{s-2+q\choose q} \frac{w^q}{(1+w)^q}
\; dw.$$

Now observe that

$$z \times \frac{1}{(1-z)^{s-1}}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} {s-2+q\choose q} z^{q+1}$$

and hence

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{s-1}} + (s-1) \frac{z}{(1-z)^s}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} (q+1) {s-2+q\choose q} z^q.$$

Evaluating this at $z=w/(1+w)$ so that $1-z = 1/(1+w)$ yields

$$(1+w)^{s-1} + (s-1) w (1+w)^{s-1}.$$

Substitute this into the integral to obtain

$$\frac{1}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r}
+ \frac{s-1}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r-1}.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r}
+ \frac{s+r}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r-1}
- {s+2r-1\choose r-1}.$$

Now

$$\frac{s+r}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r-1}
= \frac{1}{r+1} \frac{(s+2r-1)!}{(s+r-1)! (r-1)!}
\\ = \frac{r}{r+1} \frac{(s+2r-1)!}{(s+r-1)! r!}
= \frac{r}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r}.$$

Collecting everything we obtain

$$\frac{1}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r}
+ \frac{r}{r+1} {s+2r-1\choose r}
- {s+2r-1\choose r-1}
\\ = {s+2r-1\choose r}
- {s+2r-1\choose r-1}$$

as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

I use two known properties of binomial coefficients:  $${n+k \choose k} = (-1)^k {-n-1 \choose k}\tag{$i$}$$ and $$\sum_{i}{a \choose i} {b\choose c-i} = {a+b \choose c}\tag{$ii$}.$$
First,
$$
\sum_{0\le i\le r}\frac{r-i} {r+1}{2r-i\choose r-i}{s+i-2\choose i} \overset{(i)}{=} 
(-1)^r \sum_{0\le i\le r-1}\frac{r-i} {r+1}{-r-1\choose r-i}{-s+1\choose i}  \\
= (-1)^{r+1}\sum_{0\le i\le r-1}{-r-2\choose r-i-1}{-s+1\choose i}  \\\overset{(ii)}{=}  
(-1)^{r+1}{-r-s-1\choose r-1} \overset{(i)}{=}  {2r+s-1\choose r-1}.\tag{1}
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\sum_{0\le i\le r}{2r-i\choose r-i}{s+i-2\choose i} \overset{(i)}{=}  
(-1)^r \sum_{0\le i\le r}{-r-1\choose r-i}{-s+1\choose i}  \\
\overset{(ii)}{=}  (-1)^r{-r-s\choose r} \overset{(i)}{=}  {2r+s-1\choose r} \tag{2}.
$$
Subtracting (1) from (2), 
$$
\sum_{0\le i\le r}\frac{i+1} {r+1}{2r-i\choose r-i}{s+i-2\choose i} = {2r+s-1\choose r-1} - {2r+s-1\choose r}.
$$

Comment: thank you my friend , you saved me :)