# Simplify Summation of combination

Tags: combinatorics, summation, catalan-numbers

how can I simplify this to a phrase without a sigma?!

$$
{1\over r+1}{2r \choose r} + \sum_{i=1}^r \left( {i+1\over r+1} {2r-i \choose r-i}{s+i-2 \choose i} \right)
$$
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>There isn’t much you can do. Mathematica tells me the summation equals:</s>

$$\frac{2 \binom{2 r-1}{r-1} \left(\, _3F_2 \left[ {2,-r,s-1 \atop 1,-2 r} ;1 \right] -1\right)+\binom{2 r}{r}}{r+1}$$

Where $_3F_2$ is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

That basically means: as far as $\sum$s go, this one fits a sort of “nice” form, but there probably won’t be a satisfying closed form.

Here is a table of your entire equation for varying values of $r$ (row number) and $s$ (column number):

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
 2 & 5 & 9 & 14 & 20 & 27 & 35 & 44 & 54 & 65 \\
 5 & 14 & 28 & 48 & 75 & 110 & 154 & 208 & 273 & 350 \\
 14 & 42 & 90 & 165 & 275 & 429 & 637 & 910 & 1260 & 1700 \\
 42 & 132 & 297 & 572 & 1001 & 1638 & 2548 & 3808 & 5508 & 7752 \\
 132 & 429 & 1001 & 2002 & 3640 & 6188 & 9996 & 15504 & 23256 & 33915 \\
\end{array}
$$

---

**EDIT:** It appears your entire equation also equals

$$\frac{s}{r!} \prod_{k=r+1}^{2r-1} (s+k)$$

which might be what you started from in the first place!

**EDIT:** and of course, assuming $r, s$ are positive, that equals

$$\frac{s}{r} \binom{s+2r-1}{r-1}.$$

I'm seeing if I can find a good proof.

Comment: Tkanks! but would you please write the solution of it?

Comment: I mean how you find this? $$\frac{s}{r!} \prod_{k=r+1}^{2r-1} (s+k)$$

Comment: I can't find a satisfying proof. It would get very hairy to use induction. I found the formula in my first edit by looking up rows and columns from the table up in the OEIS, and noticing the patterns. I then tried it out in Mathematica and it was right.

Comment: The second formula simply followed from messing around with the first one a bit. Why did you not give any context for the problem? You tagged it [tag:catalan-numbers], and I recognize the formula but what are you trying to count?

Comment: i tagged #catalan-numbers because of the first part of phrase... I think it relevance to #catalan-numbers somehow! thanks! your answers are so useful.. i'll try to find the relevancy between the table and first formula... also any guidance from you can help... thanks again!

Comment: Someone marked this question as a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699118/calculate-sum-1-le-i-le-r-fraci1-r12r-i-choose-r-isi-2-choose-i) which has a proof